# Adding tooltip in link_to tag in rail application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a link on the index.html.erb page. Its a download link. Now I want that if the cursor hovers on the link then a tooltip text will be displayed.e
I have tried several combinations but did not get the solution yet.

My code is here:

```
<p>
Download:
<%= link_to "CSV", users_export_path(format: "csv") %> |
<%= link_to "Excel",users_export_path(format: "xls") %>
</p>
```

I installed bootstrap and I want to generate bootstrap tooltip for this two links.
Please tell what should I do along with right syntax.

Comment: I am unable to change the background color of the tooltip text and have followed Alex`s suggestion,but simply it is not working.Please someone help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the necessary data attributes in the 'link_to' helper:

```
<%= link_to "CSV", users_export_path(format: "csv"), title: 'Download CSV', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right'%> | 
<%= link_to "Excel", users_export_path(format: "xls"), title: 'Download Excel', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right'%>
```

then add the following js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

Comment: ,,, Firstly the code is working fine but tooltip text backing is just white. But I want to change the background color of the tooltip. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes..I have read the article on the link you have provided but I am using it in a rail application. So can not use class="red-tooltip" as <%= link_to "CSV", :class="red-tooltip", users_export_path(format: "csv") ,'data-toogle' => "tooltip", 'title'=>"Download CSV file" %>    Can you help me to get the right syntax.

Comment: I cant to change the color

Comment: You can use the following code
`<%= link_to "CSV", users_export_path(format: "csv"), class: 'red-tooltip', title: 'Download CSV', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right'%>`

Comment: This will add class 'red-tooltip' to your link. Then you need to write css for that class to change the background colour. `.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}`

Comment: Sorry again bro,,still not working. I have added the css code in <style></style> block

Comment: I think the problem is with the css u provided. If I omit + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner part,,,then the baclground of the Download CSV link is chabged to red,the background color of the tooltip text is not changed. But If I keep that part then no changes is made in background of tooltip part as well as the link background part.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<p>
  Download:
  <%= link_to "CSV", users_export_path(format: "csv"), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "data-placement" => "top", "title" => "Add a title" %> |
  <%= link_to "Excel",users_export_path(format: "xls"), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "data-placement" => "top", "title" => "Add a title" %>
</p>
```

And add this to your JavaScript file:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I add the Javascript line that you have provided? In the code file itself or in the jquery file. Becasuse I am using it in a rail application

Comment: In any js file under  app/assets/javascripts and require that file in application.js like this: //= require example.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<%= link_to "CSV", users_export_path(format: "csv"),  title: 'CSV' %> | <%= link_to "Excel",users_export_path(format: "xls"), title: 'XLS' %>
```

This will show a tooltip as "CSV" and "XLS" on link hower.

Answer (score 0):

I know this syntax 
`<span tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip="Your Text"></span>`

Try this way
`<span tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip="Your Text"><%= link_to "CSV", users_export_path(format: "csv") %></span>`